# Counting argument to compute the difference $\binom{n}{k} - \binom{\frac{n}{m}}{\frac{k}{m}}^m$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I was wondering if there is counting argument to compute the following difference?

$$\binom{n}{k} - \binom{\frac{n}{m}}{\frac{k}{m}}^m,$$

where m divides k and n. Obviously $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways to choose $k$ elements from a set of $n$ elements. The second term $\binom{\frac{n}{m}}{\frac{k}{m}}^m$ can be related to this. If we first split the $n$ elements into $m$ equal sized groups, then is the number of ways to choose $k$ elements such that exactly $\frac{k}{m}$ are chosen from each of the $m$ groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if the set of $n$ elements can be split into $m$ groups of size $\frac{n}{m}$ each and also $m \mid k$, the difference $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}-\binom{\frac{n}{m}}{\frac{k}{m}}^m $ is the number of ways to choose $k$ elements from the set of $n$ elements such that the numbers of elements chosen from each of the $m$ groups are not all the same.

Comment: This is true, but not useful. Still, I think this is the best answer.

Comment: @J1996 Well, the formula counts the $k$-selections excluding the "equally distributed" ones. The argument for "minus" is to exclude, the argument for binomial values is to count selections and the argument for the exponent is to multiply the number of possible $\frac{k}{m}$-selections for each of the groups. Is this more "useful"?

Thank you anyway! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let's adjust things
so all the values are integers.

$f(m, n, k)
=\binom{mn}{mk} - \binom{n}{k}^m,
$.

I have shown
using Stirling
(see below) that

$\binom{an}{bn}
\approx \sqrt{\dfrac{ a}{2\pi bn(a-b)}}\left(\dfrac{a^a}{b^b(a-b)^{a-b}}\right)^n
=\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}s(a, b)r^n(a, b)
$
with
$r(a, b)
=\dfrac{a^a}{b^b(a-b)^{a-b}}
$
and
$s(a, b)
=\sqrt{\dfrac{ a}{2\pi b(a-b)}}
=\sqrt{\dfrac{ 1}{2\pi b(1-b/a)}}
$.

If $n = 1$ this is
$\binom{a}{b}
\approx s(a, b)r(a, b)
$
so
$(\binom{a}{b})^n
\approx s^n(a, b)r^n(a, b)
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{\binom{an}{bn}}{(\binom{a}{b})^n}
&\approx \dfrac{s(a, b)r^n(a, b)}{\sqrt{n}s^n(a, b)r^n(a, b)}\\
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}s^{n-1}(a, b)}\\
\end{array}
$

Since $s(a, b ) < 1$,
$\sqrt{n}s^{n-1}(a, b)
\to 0$
as $n \to \infty$
so
$\dfrac{\binom{an}{bn}}{(\binom{a}{b})^n}
\to \infty$
as
$n \to \infty$.

Note:
Here is a proof of that assertion.

Since
$n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n$,

$\begin{array}\\
\binom{an}{bn}
&=\dfrac{(an)!}{(bn)!((a-b)n!}\\
&\sim \dfrac{\sqrt{2\pi an}(an/e)^{an}}
{(\sqrt{2\pi bn}(bn/e)^{bn})(\sqrt{2\pi n(a-b)}(((a-b)n)/e)^{(a-b)n})}\\
&= \sqrt{\dfrac{2\pi an}{2\pi bn2\pi n(a-b)}}\left(\dfrac{(an)^ae^be^{a-b}}{e^a(bn)^b((a-b)n)^{a-b}}\right)^n\\
&= \sqrt{\dfrac{ a}{2\pi bn(a-b)}}\left(\dfrac{a^an^a}{b^b(a-b)^{a-b}n^a}\right)^n\\
&= \sqrt{\dfrac{ a}{2\pi bn(a-b)}}\left(\dfrac{a^a}{b^b(a-b)^{a-b}}\right)^n\\
\end{array}
$